# Register and Resolve containers in Prism 7 - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, prism

I'm migrating an existing UWP app from Prism 6.3 to Prism 7.1.
Many changes have emerged, including how to register and resolved DI.

With prism 6.3 i was doing this :

```
Container.RegisterType<IToastNotificationsService, ToastNotificationsService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
Container.RegisterInstance<IResourceLoader>(new ResourceLoaderAdapter(new ResourceLoader()));
```

Now, with Prism 7.1, i found how to register with these lines :

```
RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IToastNotificationsService), typeof(ToastNotificationsService), true);
Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IResourceLoader), "ResourceLoader", new ResourceLoaderAdapter(new ResourceLoader()), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

But I do not succeed to use the resolve method.
For the moment i'm using it like this :

```
await Resolve(typeof(IToastNotificationsService)).ShowToastNotificationSample();
```

But I have this kind of error :

> Error CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for
>   'ShowToastNotificationSample' and no accessible extension method
>   'ShowToastNotificationSample' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Do you have any idea how to solve it cleanly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism for UWP has not yet released a stable or preview that represents the new platform. Though we hope to have this out in the near future. If you would like to try the new API you can look at the [Sandbox app](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Sandbox/Windows10/HelloWorld), and use the CI packages.

We are in the process of updating the docs, however all Prism platforms including WPF, Xamarin.Forms and UWP share common IOC abstractions. These abstractions cover most common tasks:

- Register Transient Services `(Register<T, TImp>)`
- Register Singleton Services `(RegisterSingleton<T, TImp>)`
- Register Instance `(RegisterInstance<T>(T))`

You of course have the ability to call the `GetContainer()` extension method to retrieve your container whether you're using Unity or DryIoc, in which case you can continue to work with container specific API's.